# Adding headers into split files in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm currently using a PowerShell script I found online to split down .txt (tab-delimited) files that contain a set of headers then around 1 million rows. I am looking to add something that will take the headers from the first row and copy them into each split file.

I've tried looking around online but some of the solutions I have tried seem to just create a bunch of files with just the headers then separate files with the rows of data.

```
$i=0;
Get-Content example.txt -ReadCount 50000 | %{
    $i++;
    $_ | Out-File out_$i.txt
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _each split file_. What is the question? Are you looking for a way to split the large CSV file into a series of smaller CSV files?

Comment: Hi Theo, I have a large csv that i can split into smaller files using the above code, but the new files do not contain the column headers, I am looking for something to add that would keep the column headers in each smaller file

Comment: Have you tried using `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv`?

Comment: Before your loop, just set a variable that you can reference during your loop. `$header = Get-Content example.txt -TotalCount 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the header into a variable before the loop, then write it to the output files before appending the content:

```
$header = Get-Content example.txt -TotalCount 1
Get-Content 'example.txt' -ReadCount 50000 | ForEach-Object {
    $i++
    $header | Set-Content "out_$i.txt"
    $_ | Add-Content "out_$i.txt"
}
```

Comment: Once i append and run this script it creates 1 out file with all the data in but prints an error over and over so it is trying to create each file but errors when it does.          
                                                                                                                                 
The '++' operator works only on numbers. The operand is a 'System.String'.
At line:3 char:5
+     $i++
+     ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperatorRequiresNumber

Comment: @GoldenBoy Add `[int]$i = 0` at the top of the script

Answer (score 0):

This code will split the file size and add the header that already exists to all following files. you can take out the "debuging" lines below.

```
cls
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$FileBrowser.ShowDialog()
$file = $FileBrowser.FileName
cls
Write-Host "Opening " $file
$header = Get-Content $file -First 1
Write-Host $header
$i=0; Get-Content $file -ReadCount 500 | %{$i++; if($i-gt 1){$header | Set-Content csvout-$i.csv;} $_ | Add-Content csvout-$i.csv}
```